# How to check if php script is already running

Tags: php, cron, while-loop

How to create unstoppable while loop, 
if it's already running dont run it again, I assume that if script running it will update last cron time in database, and script will check if current time - 40 seconds is less than last cron time. Sample of what I've, but that's overlooping ( running again and again do process ) Thanks!

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(1); // run script in background 
set_time_limit(0);    // set limit to 0


function processing()
{
//some function here
setting::write('cron_last_time', $time); // write cron last time to database
}

$time = current_timestamp();  // current time
$time_before = $time - 20;   //

$settings = setting::read('module_cron_email'); // Get last cron time from database ( in array )
$time_last = $settings['setting_value'];     // Last cron time get value from array



if ($time_before < $time_last) // check if time before is less than last cron time
{ 
   do{
   processing(); //run our function
   sleep(7);    // pause for 7 seconds
   continue;   // continue
   }
   while(true); // loop
}else{

echo "already running";
die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When starting the script, check for a lock file. If it does exist, quit or skip the loop. If it doesn't exist, create the file and let it run.

Comment: A "lock file" can be any old file that only by its existence is locking another script from running.  When the previously running script ends, it will delete the lock file as part of its clean up procedures.

Comment: You're right, but what if process is terminated ? It will not run again, So that's why I'm trying to do this way

Comment: What do you mean by terminated? I've forgot to mention that you have to remove the file after your script has finished.

Comment: Basic termination, when server is reloading apache or simple reboot, or just firewall has terminated process.

Comment: The standard trick is to store the pid in the lock file, and when that exists perform a `kill -0 <pid>` and use the resulting error code. (either not existant, or belongs to other uid, or zero) if the error is zero, the process (of another process run with our uid and the same process number) still exists. Extra information can be gained by grepping the output from ps.

Comment: Well you're right. You could automatically delete lock files when apache is starting. Or create a cron job which checks if a process with your php script is running, and if not, it'll attempt to delete lock files.

Comment: Why not have a file that only is representing the lock. When the loop begins you try to request a lock for the file. If not possible, it means that another script is running the procedure?

Comment: Vic's idea is actually really good. Have a look at [flock](http://php.net/manual/de/function.flock.php)

Comment: Guys you forget about executed data. Lest imagine we update 50 entries in each cron-call. How can I know that all 50 we done well? It's need for starting point of next cron-call.

Answer (score -2):

[PHP PCNTL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) is what you need! You can fork PHP processes with it.

```
                 while(true) { // Infinite

                     $pid = pcntl_fork();

                        switch (pcntl_fork($pid)) {

                                case -1:

                                        die('Fork failed');

                                        break;

                                case 0: // Child

                                        processing();

                                        exit(0);

                                        break;

                                default: // Parent

                                        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);

                                        break;

                        }

        }
```

Comment: that function has been disabled on my host